# HttpWebRequest Login - Enabled cookies on Browser

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-scraping, httpwebrequest

i have been trying from severals days to login in a web page using HttpWebRequest.
I have already done projects like this but i am stuck with this one.

I have understood that probably server needs some cookies for the request so i create a CookieContainer. This is my request:

```
Public Function Login(ByVal loginPageAddress As String, ByVal loginData As NameValueCollection) As LoginStatus
        Dim container As CookieContainer = New CookieContainer
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim retval As LoginStatus = LoginStatus.NetworkError
        Try
            
            Dim request = CType(WebRequest.Create(loginPageAddress), HttpWebRequest)
            request.Method = "POST"
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"
            Dim query = String.Join("&", loginData.Cast(Of String)().[Select](Function(key) $"{key}={loginData(key)}"))
            Dim buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(query)
            request.ContentLength = buffer.Length
            Dim requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            requestStream.Close()
            request.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
            container = request.CookieContainer
            response = request.GetResponse()
            Dim html As String = ""
            Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                html = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
            Debug.Print(html)
            If html.Contains("Reports") Then
                retval = LoginStatus.OK
            Else
                retval = LoginStatus.CrendialsError
            End If
            response.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If Not response Is Nothing Then
                response.Close()
            End If
            retval = LoginStatus.NetworkError
        End Try

        CookieContainer = container
        Return retval
    End Function
```

I had no luck cause the server responde with "Authentication failed, please enable cookies"

So i thought to add a previous request to grab the ?cookie?. In this way

```
Public Function Login(ByVal loginPageAddress As String, ByVal loginData As NameValueCollection) As LoginStatus
        Dim container As CookieContainer = New CookieContainer
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim retval As LoginStatus = LoginStatus.NetworkError
        Try
            'First request to get the cookies
            Dim requestCookies = CType(WebRequest.Create(loginPageAddress), HttpWebRequest)
            requestCookies.Method = "POST"
            requestCookies.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            requestCookies.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"
            Dim queryCookies = String.Join("&", loginData.Cast(Of String)().[Select](Function(key) $"{key}={loginData(key)}"))
            Dim bufferCookies = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(queryCookies)
            requestCookies.ContentLength = bufferCookies.Length
            Dim requestStreamCookies = requestCookies.GetRequestStream()
            requestStreamCookies.Write(bufferCookies, 0, bufferCookies.Length)
            requestStreamCookies.Close()
            requestCookies.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
   I tried to add this as well         'CookieContainer.Add(New Cookie("COOKIE_SUPPORT", "True"))

            container = requestCookies.CookieContainer
            response = requestCookies.GetResponse()
            Debug.Print("OK")

            'Login requests
            Dim request = CType(WebRequest.Create(loginPageAddress), HttpWebRequest)
            request.Method = "POST"
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"
            Dim query = String.Join("&", loginData.Cast(Of String)().[Select](Function(key) $"{key}={loginData(key)}"))
            Dim buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(query)
            request.ContentLength = buffer.Length
            Dim requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            requestStream.Close()
            request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer
            container = request.CookieContainer
            response = request.GetResponse()
            Dim html As String = ""
            Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                html = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
            Debug.Print(html)
            If html.Contains("reports") Then
                retval = LoginStatus.OK
            Else
                retval = LoginStatus.CrendialsError
            End If
            response.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If Not response Is Nothing Then
                response.Close()
            End If
            retval = LoginStatus.NetworkError
        End Try

        CookieContainer = container
        Return retval
    End Function
```

I call the function Login with this:

```
Public Function LoginWebsite() As String
        Dim retval As String = ""

        Dim loginAddress = "https://www.***********.com/home?p_auth=Fhc1hN0t&p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&saveLastPath=0&_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Flogin&_58_doActionAfterLogin=false"
        Dim loginData = New NameValueCollection From {
        {"_58_formDate", "1628523872372"},
        {"_58_redirect", ""},
        {"_58_login", "*******"},
        {"_58_password", "*******!"}
       }
        masterWebclient = New CookieAwareWebClient()
        Dim reply = masterWebclient.Login(loginAddress, loginData)
        If reply = LoginStatus.OK Then
            retval = "Logged In"
            isLoggedIn = True
        ElseIf reply = LoginStatus.CrendialsError Then
            retval = "User or password wrong"
        Else
            retval = "Network error"
        End If
        Return retval
    End Function
```

Every attempt i did was negative.
This is the header of the requests.

```
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US, en; q=0.8, es-ES; q=0.7, es; q=0.5, it-IT; q=0.3, it; q=0.2
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 89
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: NO_SPLASH_PUBLIC_SCREEN=true; JSESSIONID=98466D3D3A9259BDEBE8A294EA870CDC.GESPBEPSP02; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=**; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Mon+Aug+09+2021+19%3A46%3A49+GMT%2B0100+(GMT+Daylight+Time)&version=6.16.0&consentId=fe6ac8d3-11a8-44d7-b7ae-23f47443f131&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0004%3A1&hosts=H110%3A1%2CH107%3A1%2CH1%3A1%2CH4%3A1%2CH10%3A1%2CH12%3A1; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2021-08-09T18:46:49.040Z
Host: ******
Referer: https://*******/home?p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&saveLastPath=0&_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Flogin&p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=0&_58_redirect=%2F
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299
```

and this is the form data:

```
_58_formDate: 1628524646492
_58_redirect: 
_58_login: *****
_58_password: ******
```

I am really stuck on this from days, if anybody can tell me what i did wrong please.

EDIT: i have tried to add request cookies in this way but with no luck.

```
Dim target As Uri = New Uri("https://********")
     request.CookieContainer.Add(target, New Cookie("NO_SPLASH_PUBLIC_SCREEN", "true"))
                request.CookieContainer.Add(target, New Cookie("LFR_SESSION_STATE_1282678", "1628523959195"))
                request.CookieContainer.Add(target, New Cookie("COOKIE_SUPPORT", "true"))
                request.CookieContainer.Add(target, New Cookie("GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID", "it_IT"))
                request.CookieContainer.Add(target, New Cookie("REMOTE_USER", "******"))
                request.CookieContainer.Add(target, New Cookie("PORTLET_LIFERAY", "TRUE"))
                request.CookieContainer.Add(target, New Cookie("NO_SPLASH_PRIVATE_SCREEN", "TRUE"))
                request.CookieContainer.Add(target, New Cookie("_gid", "GA1.2.1056978425.1628437222"))
                request.CookieContainer.Add(target, New Cookie("USER_UUID", "1crDatGEA9ueMkAYIKWtS8plWx72oazquLs3l9uCEEU"))
                request.CookieContainer.Add(target, New Cookie("TICKET", "17387333"))
                request.CookieContainer.Add(target, New Cookie("LFR_SESSION_STATE_1282678", "1628523959198"))
                request.CookieContainer.Add(target, New Cookie("JSESSIONID", "JSESSIONID=662DD1C24C7A41994F00DFAB7B91F9BD.GESPBEPSP01"))
```

Edit2:

As suggest i have tried to use basic authentication. Not working but probably i make a mistake on the code.

```
   Dim request = CType(WebRequest.Create(loginPageAddress), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Dim cred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("*******", "*****","domain")  'where domain si may domain. 
    request.Credentials = cred
    request.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
    response = request.GetResponse()
```

Comment: why don't you use standard auth procedures and trying to reinvent a wheel ?

Comment: I am pretty new on this, i have tried to have a look at vb.net basic auth. I edit the question with my autentication Code, not sure to have done it right. Still same problem

Comment: first of all I suggest to use c# instead of VB. and read official documentation first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

I think, you tryed to login to the web interface, but not to API. So this server just sends cookie somewhere in another web page. Look at proper web requests in the browser.